# Can Inno Setup compiler halt upon Exec() preprocessor function failure?

Tags: inno-setup

My Inno Setup script runs a batch script while compiling using `#expr`, like so:

```
#expr Exec("\build.bat", null, null, 1)
```

By design, `#expr` ignores the return value of the `Exec()` call. This silently discards any errors, which is not desirable in my case.

Can Inno Setup be made to halt compiling upon `Exec()` failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`#if`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if) and [`#error`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=error) directives:

```
#if Exec("\build.bat", null, null, 1) != 0
    #error The build batch has failed
#endif
```